# Почему происходит ошибка переполнения стека

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Преподаватель задал задание:
Печатаешь в `QPlainText` какой либо текст, и он должен при обнаружение определенной группы символов, заменять на определенную фразу, например: `@#RUB@` заменять на "рубли" и т.д.. Мной было принято решение, отслеживать событие изменения текста в `QPlainText`, то есть на каждый ввод нового символа, я буду брать весь текст из `QPlainText`и прогонять через замену:

```
void MainWindow::on_plainTextEdit_textChanged()
{
    //ui->plainTextEdit->blockSignals(true);

    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText
    (
       ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText()
           .replace("#@RUB@", "₽", Qt::CaseInsensitive).replace("#@РУБ@", "₽", Qt::CaseInsensitive)
           .replace("#@AUTH@", "©", Qt::CaseInsensitive).replace("#@АВТП@", "©", Qt::CaseInsensitive)
           .replace("#@PM@", "‰", Qt::CaseInsensitive).replace("#@ПМ@", "‰", Qt::CaseInsensitive)
           .replace("#@GS@", "®", Qt::CaseInsensitive).replace("#@ЗК@", "®", Qt::CaseInsensitive)
           .replace("#@EURO@", "€", Qt::CaseInsensitive).replace("#@ЕВРО@", "€", Qt::CaseInsensitive)
    );

    //ui->plainTextEdit->blockSignals(false);
}
```

Вопрос, почему крашит с событием переполнения стека? Я делал по методичке и в ней, при изменении текста, в событии `textChanged()`якобы не крашит, по крайней мере пример брал от туда, вот кусок кода:

```
void MainWindow::on_plainTextEdit_textChanged()
    {
       QString str = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText(); // получаем текст виджета
       if (parseText->change(str))                     // были ли примеры
       {
           ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(parseText->getText()); // заменяем текст примеры с результатами
       }
    }
```

Отключение сигнала в момент изменения содержимого `QPlainText` помогает, но тогда возникает проблема с позицией курсора - он постоянно прыгает в начало, при вводе нового символа. Где мои ошибки, пожалуйста объясните. Версия QT 5.15.

Comment: Не уверен, но предположу, что при вызове `setPlainText` генерируется сигнал изменения текста и Вы начинаете бегать по кругу. Так что отключение сигнала это правильно, пожалуй. Просто после изменения текста нужно передвинуть курсор.  Но сама идея при вводе каждого символа перепроверять весь текст - плохая идея.

Comment: @Юрий Козлов посоветуйте, что сделать? Сохранение позиции курсора нечего не дает - он прыгает в конец либо в начало.

Comment: К сожалению, быстро не смогу помочь, я не работал с этими элементами, нужно разбираться с управлением курсором. Попробуйте задать отдельный вопрос ,может кто-то сможет помочь достаточно быстро. Да, и если Вам все-же помог предложенный ответ, пожалуйста, примите его. Для этого есть галочка слева от ответа

Comment: А если попробовать вместо `ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(parseText->getText());` изменить текст через `QTextDocument` вот так `ui->plainTextEdit->document()->setPlainText(parseText->getText());`

Comment: @Alexander Chernin это пример из методички (мой код в первом блоке), и он якобы работает нормально, у меня происходит рекурсия, зацикливание, как описал пользователь под ником Sergey Tatarincev

Comment: Да, крашит и с document(). Непонятно почему в методичке работает :) А так, да, должно зацикливаться, потому что в слоте сигнала изменения текста текст меняется и снова вставляется в виджет, который снова генерит этот сигнал - естественно зацикливание. Курсор будет улетать в начало, потому что вы "пересоздаете" текст, то есть он становится новым для виджета (в документации так написано и это ожидаемо)

Comment: @Alexander Chernin можно вопрос не по теме? Кто постоянно кидает минусы, только вопрос задал, вроде по всем правилам, адекватно и тут же минусы летят, причем заметил не только в моих темах, а во всех темах, где у автора не хватает репы посмотреть, кто это сделал, крысы одним словом, просто не хочется уже на этот форум приходить никогда, прям горит...

Comment: @Duracell я наоборот кинул +. Вопрос занятный

Comment: @ Alexander Chernin вам спасибо за советы, я к вам не с претензией) просто хотелось уточнить, замечали ли вы такое на форуме)

Answer (score 1):

Вы своими руками загоняете в рекурсию

> [signal]void QPlainTextEdit::textChanged() This signal is emitted
> whenever the document's content changes; for example, when text is
> inserted or deleted, or when formatting is applied.

Т.е. после замены текста (setPlainText()) сигнал вызовется по новой. Текст опять заменится (хоть и на тот же самый), снова вызовется сигнал. и т.д.

По решению проблемы. Можете попробовать заменять текст ТОЛЬКО если присутствуют ваши паттерны (пример для одного. остальное допишете). В идеале код надо переписать полность на использование курсоров БЕЗ полной замены текста (на больших текстах это будет работать не оптимально)

```
void MainWindow::on_plainTextEdit_textChanged()
{
    int cursorPos = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor().position(); // при замене текста курсор сдвинется в начало, поэтому запоминайте заранее
    bool isEnd = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor().atEnd(); // то же самое
    QTextCursor cur = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor();
    QString s = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();

    if(s.indexOf("#@RUB@",Qt::CaseInsensitive)!=-1){
        ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(s.replace("#@RUB@", "₽", Qt::CaseInsensitive));
        qApp->processEvents();
        if(isEnd){ // паттерн дописан в конец текста или в середину?
            cur.movePosition(QTextCursor::End); // курсор в конец текста
        }else{
            cur.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start); // перемещаем курсор в начало
            cur.movePosition(QTextCursor::Right,QTextCursor::MoveAnchor,cursorPos-5); // перемещаем вправо на cursorPos-5 (длина паттерна-1)
        }
        ui->plainTextEdit->setTextCursor(cur);
    }
}
```

Comment: Тот же самый эффект, что и с блокировкой сигналов - курсор перепрыгивает в начало строки, я как только не пытался сохранять позицию курсора, он либо постоянно прыгает в начало, или в конец.

Comment: переписал ответ. так работать будет, но в идеале переписать на курсоры - выделение паттерна курсором, удаление выделенного, вставка нового текста, но тут все карты вам в руки. Да прибудет с вами сила.

Comment: Tatarincev спасибо вам большое за помощь! Я тоже так делал, но хотел в идеале, перемещать курсор на то место, где он был последний раз, до того как произошла замена, например, возможна ситуация, когда в уже напечатанный текст, хочешь куда-нибудь в середину текста внести эти специальные символы...Не важно крч, еще раз спасибо за ответ, я работу уже сдал с недочетами.